# Multiple objects in variable declaration

Tags: jquery

I came across variable declaration wherein is multiple objects. Here's code:

```
var $slider = $('#slider');
var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
```

Can somebody explain me how it works?

Comment: Read the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Comment: Just wondering why my answer wasn't accepted. It's correct, and it's the only one.

Answer (score 0):

It selects the combined results of each selector.

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/